# C++ concept to type trait

Tags: c++, type-traits, c++-concepts

I have a concept as follows:

```
template<class T>
concept Reader = requires(T a)
{...};
```

I want to have a type trait which checks if a class conforms to the `Reader` concept - Something like `is_reader<myclass>::value`. **How do I achieve this?**

My attempts till now has been something like:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_reader : std::false_type;

template<Reader T>
struct is_reader : std::true_type;
```

This doesn't compile due to re-declaration of template type.

I also tried:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_reader : std::false_type;

template<>
struct is_reader<Reader auto> : std::true_type;
```

While this compiles, it does not work.

How to make this work? **Also why does my second try not work - What is it doing?**

Comment: I wonder why? What concept can't do and type trait can? Or what type trait can do better than concept? I suspect that only reason is that type trait is just more familiar.

Comment: @MarekR I don't need type trait at all. Just easier to get some debug traces. Also I got stumped while trying to come up with the type trait. So this is more of a curiosity question rather than practical application.

Comment: `auto` will deduce a non-type parameter in template contexts. A non-type that satisfies `Reader` can never be the type `Reader`. It's a partial specialization that will never match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way is

```
template<class T>
concept Reader = requires(T a) {...};

template<typename T>
struct is_reader : std::false_type {};

template<Reader T>
struct is_reader<T> : std::true_type {};
```

Comment: Any idea what was happening with my second attempt?

Comment: @tinkerbeast `auto` keyword can't be used in that contract. It denotes deduced type, which isn't  the case here.. or so far as you had shown.

Answer (score 2):

Concepts can be directly evaluated as boolean expressions:

```cpp
#include <concepts>

static_assert(std::signed_integral<int>);
static_assert(!std::signed_integral<unsigned>);
```

[Live demo (godbolt)](https://godbolt.org/z/5PKn4TGzc)

---

So you can get rid of SFINAE, and simply write:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct is_reader : std::bool_constant<Reader<T>> {};
```

[Live demo (godbolt)](https://godbolt.org/z/z85eaMWMd)